# Booking Ride with Uber API

Tags: uber-api

When I look up products I can get the `product_id` that has `upfront_fare_enabled` as true.

I then get the `fare_id`.

However when I use that `fare_id` to book a ride, I always get the error below;

> {"meta":{},"errors":[{"status":422,"code":"upfront_fare_required","title":"A
>   valid fare_id is required to request a trip with this product."}]}

Also, the `product_id` that clearly says `upfront_fare_enabled` is true.

If I lookup that product id it just says

```
"{"fare":{"breakdown":[{"type":"base_fare","name":"Base Fare","value":10.4}],"value":10.4"}"}"
```

Nothing about `upfront_fare_enabled`.

I've cross-checked; the `product_id` is correct.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the API docs https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/curl

> The Uber API lets you Request an Uber Product for riders. Given you
>   know a rider’s location, where they want to go, and which Uber product
>   they want, you can request a ride for them with a few simple API
>   endpoints.
>
> In the products endpoint GET /products, products have the
>   upfront_fare_enabled field set to true.
>
> Use the request estimate
>   endpoint POST /requests/estimate with a product_id to get a fare_id.
>   The fare_id is used to set an upfront fare and arrival time for a
>   trip. The fare_id expires after two minutes. If the fare_id expires or
>   isn’t valid, a 422 error is returned.
>
> Request a ride using the request
>   endpoint POST /requests with the fare_id returned in the previous
>   step.

See the API docs for the two APIs here

https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-estimate-post#example-response-with-surge-pricing

https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-post#post-parameters

Comment: Not working still :(

I do a lookup of the product before I try to book the ride.

{"products":[{"upfront_fare_enabled":true,"capacity":4,"product_id":"28fc0b4e-3f7f-431a-889e-84e9cb4192e1",

Fare ID call works no propblem using same address.

{"fare":{"breakdown":[{"type":"base_fare","name":"Base Fare","value":10.59}],"value":10.59,"fare_id":"b2b8644ff572bcd80f1de440238a7ed4885f731a21e1424a8240a970d15760da",

Booking the ride however.

{"meta":{},"errors":[{"status":422,"code":"upfront_fare_required","title":"A valid fare_id is required to request a trip with this product."}]}

Comment: I suggest you post more of your code, it's really hard to guess from the snippets of output you have provided.